# Minimum & Maximum character amounts Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm still new to regex, and I'm trying to create a regex for verifying ids for an app I am creating.

The id constraints are as follows -

- Can only begin with either `A-Z`, `a-z`, `,`, `'`, `-`.
- Can contain all of the above and also `.`, just not at the beginning.
- Must have at least two `A-Z | a-z` characters
- And characters can only appear once. (`,,` shouldn't match, only `,`)

**EDIT:** I was unclear about the fourth point, it should only disallow consecutive symbols, but not consecutive letters.

So far all I have is

```
^(A-Za-z',-)(A-Za-z',-\\.)+$        // I'm using java hence the reason for the `\\.`
```

I don't know how to match a specific amount of things within my regex. I would imagine it is something simple, but any help would be very useful.

I'm very new to regex and I'm really lost as to how to do this.

**Edit:** final regex is as follows

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*)(?!.*(,|'|\-|\.)\1.*)[A-Za-z,'\-][A-Za-z,'\-\.]*
```

Thanks to Ro Yo Mi and RebelWitoutAPulse!

Comment: Can't really do that with regex. Why are you trying to do it with regex? To quote Jamie Zawinski: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: I figured. I've never actually used regex before, so I figured it would be a good to learn. I don't know the limitations, and thus I wasn't sure if it would be possible.

Comment: You can do the first two bullets with regex, and you almost have that, if you just replace the `()` with `[]` and escape the `-`. You might be able to tweak the regex to do bullet 3, but it'll be ugly, however there is no way to do bullet 4 with regex.

Comment: How exactly would I go about completing bullet three? I can do bullet four through Java (and honestly all of them, if I wanted), but I'd like to see how one would go about bullet three, be it unconventional.

Comment: @Andreas if I were to use a second regex `(?:A-Za-z){2,}` would work in unison with `^[A-Za-z',\\-][A-Za-z',\\-\\.]+$`?

Comment: Since first character is special (no `.`), you have two cases: 1) Initial letter, zero or more non-letters, a second letter, zero or more valid characters. 2) Initial non-letter, zero or more non-letters, a letter, zero or more non-letters, a second letter, zero or more valid characters. --- So *(spaces added for readability, no escape needed for `-` if last)*: `[a-zA-Z] [.,'-]* [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z.,'-]*  |  [,'-] [.,'-]* [a-zA-Z] [.,'-]* [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z.,'-]*` --- Since 1st set is same as last 4 pieces for 2nd set, it collapses to: `(?: [,'-] [.,'-]* )? [a-zA-Z] [.,'-]* [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z.,'-]*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the positive/negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Rough explanation of this technique is that when regex processor encounters it - it suspends further regex processing until subregex defined inside the lookahead is matched.

The regex might be:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*)(?!.*(.)\1.*)[A-Za-z,'\-][A-Za-z,'\-\.]*
```

Explanation:

- `^` - beginning of the string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*)` - continue matching only if string has any amount of any characters, followed by something from `a-Z`, then again any amount of any character, then again `a-Z`, then anything. This effectively covers **point 3**.
- `(?!.*(.)\1.*)` - stop matching if there are duplicate consequitive characters in the string. It checks for anything, then remembers a character using a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and checks the remainder for the string for occurence of character from capture group. This covers **point 4**.

  **Note**: if point 4 meant that every character in the string should be unique, then you may add `.*` between `(.)` and `\1`.

  **Note**: if this matches - the regex processing "caret" is back at the beginning of the string.
- `[A-Za-z,'\-]` - the "real" matching begins. Character class matches your requirement from **point 1**.
- `[A-Za-z,'\-\.]*` - any amount of characters mentioned in **point 1** and **point 4**

Not sure about java regex specifics - quick google search found that this might be possible. Synthetic test works:

```
Astring # match
,string # match

.string # does not match

a.- # does not match: there are no two characters from [a-Z]

doesnotmatch  # does not match: double non-consequitive occurrence of 't'
```

P.S. The regex may be optimised quite a lot if one were to use the defined character classes instead of a `.` - but this would add quite a lot of visual clutter to the answer.

Comment: This is great! I wasn't very clear on my fourth point, I had only intended to disallow duplicate symbols, not also letters. My fault.

Comment: Okay, to fix this I replaced `(?!.*(.)\1.*)` with `(?!.*(,|'|\-|\.)\1.*)`. Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

```regex
^(?!\.)(?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){2})(?:([a-zA-Z,'.-])(?!.*?\1))+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- `(?!\.)`

  - validates the string does not start with a `.`
- `(?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){2})`

  - validates the string has at least two `A-Z | a-z` characters
- `(?:([a-zA-Z,'.-])(?!.*?\1))+`

  - allows the string to only contain a-z, A-Z, `,`, `.`, `-`
  - Allows characters to only appear once. (`,,` shouldn't match, only `,`)

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/hO2mU1/1

**Sample text**

```
-abced
aabdefsa
abcdefs
.abded
ac.dC
ab
a.b
```

**Sample Matches**

```
-abced
abcdefs
ac.dC
ab
a.b
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Za-z]                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
                               'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2}                     end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-zA-Z,'.-]             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                               'Z', ',', ''', '.', '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```